# The text gets upon the image.Why this is happening?

Tags: swiftui

The text gets upon the image.Why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: please include your full code here, this is very difficult to read and check.

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is what happens:

1. The image placeholder container is rendered with a frame height of 300
2. The text is rendered below the container
3. The asynchronous image downloads and is set with a `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` modifier
4. If the downloaded image, modified to fill the container, end up with a height over 300 it will spill out from the container and render below the text.

What you can do is to center crop your image:

```
//For your specific case
image
  .resizable()
  .scaledToFill()
  .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
  .clipped()
```